# Missing firewallD in CentOS 7 VPS

Tags: iptables, centos7, firewalld, systemctl, ovh

i fresh installed CentOS 7 in a OVH VPS. but when i ran the command `firewall-cmd` i got this:

```
-bash: firewall-cmd: command not found
```

so i was looking how resolve that and i saw that basically i needed to install it.

So I was trying to fully disable iptables with: `systemctl mask iptables` but i received a error that i strange because i was running as root:

```
Failed to execute operation: Access denied
```

I tried the following commands too before:

```
[root@vps****** ~]# systemctl status iptables
● iptables.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

and

```
[root@vps****** ~]# systemctl stop iptables
Failed to stop iptables.service: Unit iptables.service not loaded.
```

so i thought that iptables was not installed as well but when i run the command `iptables --version` i get `iptables v1.4.21` so i guess it it installed...

**So, what is causing iptables not be recognized with systemctl and why firewallD is not installed as default?**

some people have similar problem because OpenVZ, but OVH don't use OpenVZ anymore...

system info:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/osrelease 
3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64
```

--

```
cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
```

Comment: You can't mask a service that isn't installed!

Comment: @MichaelHampton but it is installed. then why i get `iptables v1.4.21` when i run `iptables --version`

Comment: That is the iptables command, it is not a service. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MichaelHampton i'm trying replacing iptables with firewalld

Comment: In that case you need to install firewalld.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=install+firewalld+in+centos+7 helps?

Comment: and just remove the iptables package too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I remember having seen something peculiar on OVH's VPS. In my case, if I remember well, everything was compiled into the kernel -- there were no kernel modules loaded dynamically.

In your case you don't need to bother disabling iptables -- I'm not even sure that you can, since firewalld uses iptables underneath. Simply install and configure firewalld and you'll be fine.